# How do I know which version of .net my application is consuming from my multi-targeted library

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-standard, .net-core-3.1

I have 2 class libs, and one web application.

My class lib WebExtensions compiles to netstandard2.0/netcoreapp3.1/netframework4.8, but has preprocessor directives to bring in different usings dependant on the framework...

```
IF NETCOREAPP3.1
  USING  THIS
ELSE
  USING THIS
```

My Data Access class library uses my Web Extensions library, and this only compiles to `NetStandard2.0` and  `Netframework 4.8`

My web application compiles to `netcoreapp3.1`

How do I know what preprocessor bit my web app is using?

Is it using `NETCOREAPP3.1` as that's what my web app compiles to? Or is it only using `NetStandard2.0` as that's what my DataAccess library compiles to, that references it?

For reference:

```
Web Extensions - netstandard2.0/netcoreapp3.1/netframework4.8 -> DataAccess netstandard2.0/netframework4.8 -> Web App netcoreapp3.1
```

Comment: I don't really know know the answer, though I suspect it will be netcoreapp3.1, but what I suggest is to just do conditional Console.Writeline or some similar to figure it out for sure.

Comment: That is a very good idea!